# Unity : No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

Below code is to Initialize Dependency Injection Container in application global.asax

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainerFactory().CreateConfiguredContainer();
var serviceLocator = new UnityServiceLocator(container);
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => serviceLocator);
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

But application is always failing with parameter less constructor exception for 
HomeController, below is the exception.

**Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "MyApp.Web.Controllers.HomeController", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.**

### Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

At the time of the exception, the container was:

Resolving MyApp.Web.Controllers.HomeController,(none)
  Resolving parameter "serviceLocator" of constructor MyApp.Web.Controllers.HomeController(Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator serviceLocator)
    Resolving Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator,(none)

**Below is the inner exception of the exception.**

at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.ThrowForAttemptingToConstructInterface(IBuilderContext context) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity\Src\ObjectBuilder\Strategies\BuildPlan\DynamicMethod\Creation\DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.cs:line 207
   at BuildUp_Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator(IBuilderContext )
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity\Src\ObjectBuilder\Strategies\BuildPlan\BuildPlanStrategy.cs:line 43
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity\Src\ObjectBuilder\Strategies\StrategyChain.cs:line 112
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity\Src\ObjectBuilder\BuilderContext.cs:line 215
   at BuildUp_MyApp.Web.Controllers.HomeController(IBuilderContext )
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity\Src\ObjectBuilder\Strategies\BuildPlan\BuildPlanStrategy.cs:line 43
   at Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity\Src\ObjectBuilder\Strategies\StrategyChain.cs:line 112
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) in e:\Builds\Unity\UnityTemp\Compile\Unity\Unity\Src\UnityContainer.cs:line 511

Microsoft.Practices.Unity 2.0.414.0 has been used. What is the issue with implementation, am I missing something?

Comment: have you defined  constructor inside controller?

Comment: Not without parameter, unity should inject type with defined parameter  constructor.

Comment: where have you registered type that will be injected as parameter in constructor?

Comment: Why are you injecting the `ServiceLocator` instead of the actual dependencies?

Comment: Type mapping is in config file.

Comment: You shouldn't be injecting a ServiceLocator, that's an architectural mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor presumably has the following signature

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  public HomeController( IServiceLocator locator )
  {
      ...
```

Unity follows the signature and tries to find a concrete type mapped to the interface, registered in your container. But there is none.

What you do however, is a mistake. You should be injecting actual dependencies to services / business objects, not to the infrastructure class a service locator is.

```
 public HomeController( ISomeService service, IAnotherService another )
```

Unity would resolve these, assuming you first map abstractions to concrete types.

Comment: Now understood the role of servicelocator which has been implemented in application, its a wrong implementation, may be some one thought  to inject servicelocator itself LOL.... Thanks Wiktor since service-locator getting initialized on app start I made bit change and rely what available in current context of service locator.

Comment: One question still roaming in my mind, why it was failing during http redirect or http post?

Comment: @Hi10 it will fail that way on every *request* that reaches that controller because how controllers work in ASP.Net MVC

Comment: But surprise is, first time application launch no issue things work but sudden navigation fails. I will investigate more thanks for the answer Alex.

Answer (score 3):

You need to register all interfaces your controller relies on. In this case

```
HomeController(Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator serviceLocator) {...}
```

Means you need to have line like

```
container.RegisterType<IServiceLocator, SomeServiceLocatorImpl>();
```

Note that it is generally better practice to depend on required interfaces instead on `IServiceLocator` - [How to avoid Service Locator Anti-Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833995/how-to-avoid-service-locator-anti-pattern)

Comment: If I go with  container.RegisterType<IServiceLocator, SomeServiceLocatorImpl>(); this then don't it become fixed? I want to be flexible to control with config file